# The scope of arguments in Class in c++

Tags: c++, class, initialization

I have this class in c++ that basically prints out "cat1". Following is the code:

```
class Cat {
public:
        Cat(const std::string h = "")
        : name(h)
        {
                std::cout << "Cat " << name << " created." << std::endl;
        }
        void eatFood(){
                std::cout << "Food eaten by cat named " << name << "." << std::endl;
        }

        std::string name="";
};

Cat makeCat2() {
        return Cat("Cat2");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Cat kit = makeCat2();
    kit.eatFood();
}
```

THe result is

```
Cat Cat2 created
Food eaten by cat named Cat2
```

But when instead of changing the argument declaration of the class Cat from

```
Cat(const std::string h = "")
        : name(h)
```

to

```
Cat(const std::string name = "")
```

The result is

```
Cat Cat2 created
Food eaten by cat named
```

So my question is why if we change from std::string h = "" to directly assiging the arguments to name via std::string name= "" then why is string variable "name" is not stored or updated i.e when member function eatfood() prints "name" nothing prints out which is initial value. In other words the only way to update the arugument cat2 in member function is to use initialization method using name(h)?

Comment: There is no code here that will print "cat1"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two variables named `name` here.

The first is the parameter to the constructor, which is only in scope for that constructor (this is the same variable that you instead called `h` in the other example).

The second is the member variable.

If you don't set the second to the same value as the first, that value is never stored anywhere and will be "lost" when the constructor ends.

Comment: Makes so much sense I even tried {   Cat(const std::string name = "")
        : name(name) } it works because "name" in parameter is different then "name" in member variable. Thanks!

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER: Exactly :) It's not very clear of C++ here, but that's how the scope rules work. Some people encourage the use of silly prefixes on member names to make this clearer (like `m_name`) though I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter has no implicit connection to the member variable.

So you have two options:

first use the initializer list:

```
Cat(const std::string h = "")
    : name(h)
```

or initialize the variable yourself in the constructor:

```
 Cat(const std::string h = "") {
    this->name = h;
 }
```

Comment: Both the form works, the confusion was that I was not aware that "name" in the parameter of constructor is different then "name" in the member variable.